# How to notify HTTP client of the completion of a long task

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I have a Node.js system that uploads a large number of objects to MongoDB and creates folders in dropbox for each object. This takes around 0.5 seconds per object. In situations therefore where i have many objects this could take up to around a minute. What i currently do is notify the client that the array of objects has been accepted using a `202` response code. However how do i then notify the client of completion a minute later.

```
app.post('/BulkAdd', function (req, res) {
    issues = []
    console.log(req.body)
    res.status(202).send({response:"Processing"});
    api_functions.bulkAdd(req.body).then( (failed, issues, success) => {
        console.log('done')
    })

});


bulkAdd: async function (req, callback) {
  let failed = []
  let issues = []
  let success = []
  i = 1

  await req.reduce((promise, audit) => {
    // return promise.then(_ => dropbox_functions.createFolder(audit.scanner_ui)
    let globalData;
  return promise.then(_ => this.add(audit)
      .then((data)=> {globalData = data; return dropbox_functions.createFolder(data.ui, data)}, (error)=> {failed.push({audit: audit, error: 'There was an error adding this case to the database'}); console.log(error)})
        .then((data)=>{console.log(data, globalData);return dropbox_functions.checkScannerFolderExists(audit.scanner_ui)},(error)=>{issues.push({audit: globalData, error: 'There was an error creating the case folder in dropbox'})})
         .then((data)=>{return dropbox_functions.moveFolder(audit.scanner_ui, globalData.ui)},(error)=>{issues.push({audit: globalData, error: 'No data folder was found so an empty one was created'}); return dropbox_functions.createDataFolder(globalData.ui)})
          .then(()=>success.push({audit:globalData}), issues.push({audit: globalData, error: 'Scanner folder found but items not moved'}))
    );
  }, Promise.resolve()).catch(error => {console.log(error)});
  return(failed, issues, success)

},
```

Comment: Since you haven't included any code all I can suggest is to use `setTimeout(()=>{ notifyUser(); }, 60000);`

Comment: If you're using `node` look into something like `Node Webhooks`

Comment: An HTTP response is stateless, IOW: once you have returned the page, there is no more interaction.  There are 2 options,   1: Use a long poling request, (but this can be tricky to get right).  2. Use websockets to communicate progress.  In fact using websockets from the outset is a really nice way for node.js to communicate with HTTP clients.

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem with making client request wait, is it will timeout after certain period or sometimes will show error with `no response received`.

What you can do is

```
 - Make client request to server to initiate the task, and return 200OK and keep doing your task on server. 
 - Now write a file on server after insertion of every object as status. 
 - Read the file from client every 5-10 sec to check if server has completed creating objects or not. 
 - Mean while your task is not completed on server, show status with completion percentage or some animation.
```

Or simply implement `WebHook` or `WebSockets` to maintain communication.